# How to slice the big array and return the sliced array based upon value of the argument page_no?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I've a big array titled `$data`. For your reference I'm putting below only 14 elements of it. Practically it may contain hundreds of such elements:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 16
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 199
                    [profile_page_id] => 0
                    [user_server_id] => 0
                    [user_name] => profile-199
                    [full_name] => Benjamin Jordon
                    [gender] => 0
                    [user_image] => 
                    [is_invisible] => 0
                    [user_group_id] => 6
                    [language_id] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 901
                    [profile_page_id] => 0
                    [user_server_id] => 1
                    [user_name] => profile-901
                    [full_name] => Campusknot .
                    [gender] => 0
                    [user_image] => 2014/11/b23e023750785c8b5e61ace4d6a202fa%s.png
                    [is_invisible] => 0
                    [user_group_id] => 6
                    [language_id] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 244
                    [profile_page_id] => 0
                    [user_server_id] => 0
                    [user_name] => profile-244
                    [full_name] => Campusknot .
                    [gender] => 0
                    [user_image] => 2015/02/0f34dbb95ce18b17611220b78c87f9a6%s.png
                    [is_invisible] => 0
                    [user_group_id] => 7
                    [language_id] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 200
                    [profile_page_id] => 0
                    [user_server_id] => 0
                    [user_name] => profile-200
                    [full_name] => Derius Galvez
                    [gender] => 0
                    [user_image] => 
                    [is_invisible] => 0
                    [user_group_id] => 6
                    [language_id] => 
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 109
                    [profile_page_id] => 0
                    [user_server_id] => 0
                    [user_name] => profile-109
                    [full_name] => Hiten patel
                    [gender] => 0
                    [user_image] => 
                    [is_invisible] => 0
                    [user_group_id] => 6
                    [language_id] => 
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 204
                    [profile_page_id] => 0
                    [user_server_id] => 0
                    [user_name] => profile-204
                    [full_name] => Huong Nguyen
                    [gender] => 0
                    [user_image] => 
                    [is_invisible] => 0
                    [user_group_id] => 6
                    [language_id] => 
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 196
                    [profile_page_id] => 0
                    [user_server_id] => 1
                    [user_name] => profile-196
                    [full_name] => Ira Hampton
                    [gender] => 1
                    [user_image] => 2014/11/24c4a6835e667b67b82cea3666841ac7%s.jpg
                    [is_invisible] => 0
                    [user_group_id] => 6
                    [language_id] => 
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 211
                    [profile_page_id] => 0
                    [user_server_id] => 0
                    [user_name] => profile-211
                    [full_name] => Kevin Rolando Vilcapaza Diaz
                    [gender] => 1
                    [user_image] => 
                    [is_invisible] => 0
                    [user_group_id] => 6
                    [language_id] => 
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 202
                    [profile_page_id] => 0
                    [user_server_id] => 1
                    [user_name] => profile-202
                    [full_name] => Mai Le
                    [gender] => 0
                    [user_image] => 2014/08/ebaf98a8b7875b4814b06baceaccad22%s.jpg
                    [is_invisible] => 0
                    [user_group_id] => 6
                    [language_id] => 
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 185
                    [profile_page_id] => 0
                    [user_server_id] => 1
                    [user_name] => profile-185
                    [full_name] => Perceus Mody
                    [gender] => 1
                    [user_image] => 2014/09/5f86df8752fd7079296c0101d235a592%s.jpg
                    [is_invisible] => 0
                    [user_group_id] => 6
                    [language_id] => 
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 205
                    [profile_page_id] => 0
                    [user_server_id] => 1
                    [user_name] => profile-205
                    [full_name] => Phong Phan
                    [gender] => 0
                    [user_image] => 2014/08/d32361f1f72a4e24b9c8329501bc8aa1%s.jpg
                    [is_invisible] => 0
                    [user_group_id] => 6
                    [language_id] => 
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 201
                    [profile_page_id] => 0
                    [user_server_id] => 1
                    [user_name] => profile-201
                    [full_name] => Rahul Gopal
                    [gender] => 1
                    [user_image] => 2014/09/d936e72dbad21732812c33e80752aad6%s.png
                    [is_invisible] => 0
                    [user_group_id] => 6
                    [language_id] => 
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 208
                    [profile_page_id] => 0
                    [user_server_id] => 0
                    [user_name] => profile-208
                    [full_name] => SHUVAM SAHA
                    [gender] => 0
                    [user_image] => 
                    [is_invisible] => 0
                    [user_group_id] => 6
                    [language_id] => 
                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 212
                    [profile_page_id] => 0
                    [user_server_id] => 0
                    [user_name] => profile-212
                    [full_name] => Turner Corbin
                    [gender] => 0
                    [user_image] => 
                    [is_invisible] => 0
                    [user_group_id] => 6
                    [language_id] => 
                )

        )

)
```

From the above array please ignore the first key-value pair i.e.`[0] => 16`. Consider array present in `[1]` that contains 14 elements.

Now what I want is a function to which I'll pass the array `$data` and an argument `page_no`.

Suppose, if I've passed `page_no=1` then I should got first 10 records in return i.e. the following array:

```
Array
    (

                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => 199
                        [profile_page_id] => 0
                        [user_server_id] => 0
                        [user_name] => profile-199
                        [full_name] => Benjamin Jordon
                        [gender] => 0
                        [user_image] => 
                        [is_invisible] => 0
                        [user_group_id] => 6
                        [language_id] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => 901
                        [profile_page_id] => 0
                        [user_server_id] => 1
                        [user_name] => profile-901
                        [full_name] => Campusknot .
                        [gender] => 0
                        [user_image] => 2014/11/b23e023750785c8b5e61ace4d6a202fa%s.png
                        [is_invisible] => 0
                        [user_group_id] => 6
                        [language_id] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => 244
                        [profile_page_id] => 0
                        [user_server_id] => 0
                        [user_name] => profile-244
                        [full_name] => Campusknot .
                        [gender] => 0
                        [user_image] => 2015/02/0f34dbb95ce18b17611220b78c87f9a6%s.png
                        [is_invisible] => 0
                        [user_group_id] => 7
                        [language_id] => 
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => 200
                        [profile_page_id] => 0
                        [user_server_id] => 0
                        [user_name] => profile-200
                        [full_name] => Derius Galvez
                        [gender] => 0
                        [user_image] => 
                        [is_invisible] => 0
                        [user_group_id] => 6
                        [language_id] => 
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => 109
                        [profile_page_id] => 0
                        [user_server_id] => 0
                        [user_name] => profile-109
                        [full_name] => Hiten patel
                        [gender] => 0
                        [user_image] => 
                        [is_invisible] => 0
                        [user_group_id] => 6
                        [language_id] => 
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => 204
                        [profile_page_id] => 0
                        [user_server_id] => 0
                        [user_name] => profile-204
                        [full_name] => Huong Nguyen
                        [gender] => 0
                        [user_image] => 
                        [is_invisible] => 0
                        [user_group_id] => 6
                        [language_id] => 
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => 196
                        [profile_page_id] => 0
                        [user_server_id] => 1
                        [user_name] => profile-196
                        [full_name] => Ira Hampton
                        [gender] => 1
                        [user_image] => 2014/11/24c4a6835e667b67b82cea3666841ac7%s.jpg
                        [is_invisible] => 0
                        [user_group_id] => 6
                        [language_id] => 
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => 211
                        [profile_page_id] => 0
                        [user_server_id] => 0
                        [user_name] => profile-211
                        [full_name] => Kevin Rolando Vilcapaza Diaz
                        [gender] => 1
                        [user_image] => 
                        [is_invisible] => 0
                        [user_group_id] => 6
                        [language_id] => 
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => 202
                        [profile_page_id] => 0
                        [user_server_id] => 1
                        [user_name] => profile-202
                        [full_name] => Mai Le
                        [gender] => 0
                        [user_image] => 2014/08/ebaf98a8b7875b4814b06baceaccad22%s.jpg
                        [is_invisible] => 0
                        [user_group_id] => 6
                        [language_id] => 
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [user_id] => 185
                        [profile_page_id] => 0
                        [user_server_id] => 1
                        [user_name] => profile-185
                        [full_name] => Perceus Mody
                        [gender] => 1
                        [user_image] => 2014/09/5f86df8752fd7079296c0101d235a592%s.jpg
                        [is_invisible] => 0
                        [user_group_id] => 6
                        [language_id] => 
                    )           

    )
```

then if I pass page_no =2 then the subsequent set or records i.e.keys `[10],[11],[12],[13]` should get in return. The array keys should not start again from `[0]`. In other words I want array elements in bunch of 10 or less elements based on the value of argument page_no with original array keys intact.

If no element is present for a specific page number then it should return false.

How should I do this in an efficient way since the actual array might be very huge in size with hundreds of such elements? Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :-

```
$input = array('', ................);

$pageno = 1
$numberofrecords = 10;


$array_end = $pageno * 10;
$array_e= $array_end  -  1;



$numbers =  $numberofrecords - 1;
$array_start = $array_e - $numbers;


print_r(array_slice($input,$array_start,$array_e));
```

Comment: If you could give the complete workable code containing the function call and function definition it would be really helpful.

Comment: Just pass your array in $input vriable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function slice($data = array(), $pageNo = null)
{
    if (is_null($data)) {
        return array();
    } else {
        if ($pageNo == null || $pageNo == 1) {
            $ctr = 0;
            for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
                if (isset($data[$ctr])) {
                    $dataSliced[] = $data[$ctr];
                    $ctr++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $ctr = ($pageNo * 10) - 10;
            for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
               if (isset($data[$ctr])) {
                  $dataSliced[] = $data[$ctr];
                  $ctr++;
               }
            }
        }
        return $dataSliced;
    }
}
```

This function checked is `$data` is null and will return an empty array, else it will check for the `$pageNo` that controls the array that will be returned, if `$pageNo` is empty or 1 the `$ctr` which is the control variable to know index of the data it will get hence it will get the index 0 of the data else it will get index for next 10 records if the index is 2 and so forth. hope it helps.

or if you want the [array_slice](http://www.example.com/) method for php you can try this:

```
function slice($data = array(), $pageNo = null)
{
    if (is_null($data)) {
        return array();
    } else {
        if ($pageNo) {
            $ctr = ($pageNo * 10) - 10;
            $dataSliced = array_slice($data, $ctr, 10); 
        }
        return $dataSliced;
    }
}
```